# Typescript generic for function with a variable number of parameters

Tags: typescript, generics, types

I have a function that takes an arbitrary number of classes.

```
function findObjects(...Classes) { ... }
```

All classes inherit from one `Component` class. This function in a certain way searches for objects that are instances of these classes.

How to implement a template for functions with a variable number of parameters?

It should be something like this:

```
function findObjects(...Classes): [...Classes] { ... }
```

This is necessary for the correct definition of types and for the correct operation of intellisense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to have a look at [tuple rest parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#rest-parameters), which are used to emulate functions with a [variable number of parameters](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5453). A possible solution:

```
// We pass in a tuple of classes. This tuple is generically typed (type parameter T)
// { new(...arg: any): any } is constructor function type for a class
function findObjects<T extends { new(...arg: any): any }[]>(...cls: T): Partial<T> {
  // search for objects that are instances of these classes; return filtered classes
}

class Component { c = "c" }
class A extends Component { a = "a" }
class B extends Component { b = "b" }

const res = findObjects(A, B) // [(typeof A | undefined)?, (typeof B | undefined)?]
```

For the return type I used `Partial<T>`, which is a [mapped tuple with optional elements](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#optional-elements-in-tuple-types) of the passed in classes. It contains `undefined` at an index, if the corresponding class item is filtered out by your `findObjects` implementation (adjust the return type like you need it).

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=13&ssc=30&pln=13&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMGYAmB5ARgKwKbQDOAPACqJ4AeUe6hiA3omHgO4AUAdNwIYBOAcwBciHmACeAShFjxiAL4BtALoA%20LtwgAbQiNLTEABX6weWsqsYBYAFCJ7iAPSPEhPPwgALZHD6I4uARQ9FCePFCifHiIqIRQYhB49HDAiKFJ0do8hG6EnLYOTi5RUCB8SChaNFFoiFk5Sbbytrb19ADCcAC2AA4ItBFMEIgAvIgARBDjCi02bYgAghTUtGgd3X0sYIOioxM80802rVrZ9ABCyzR0iJ29-duMiFh741iHs60IcYhR9GModDYfBEdgLAA0iHOklsQA)

Comment: Thanks! Tell me how to write it in jsdoc? Tried like this: `@param  {T extends { new(...arg: any): any }[]} Classes @returns {Partial<T>} @template T`. But return type is not displayed correctly.

Comment: @pank Hm, I actually never used JSDoc with TypeScript. According to [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-checking-javascript-files.html#template), it seems to be possible to add a type constraint for `T` in the template. Something like: `@template {{ new(...arg: any): any }[]} T  @param {T} cls @returns {Partial<T>}`

Answer (score 1):

You can use rest parameters as described in the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#rest-parameters)

```
interface A { }

class B implements A { }


class C implements A { }


function findObjects(...objs: A[]): A[] {
  // function body

}

const obj1: B = {}
const obj2: C = {}

const result1 = findObjects(obj1);
const result2 = findObjects(obj1, obj2);
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: `[A]` means you get 1 element tuple not an array. Correct type is `A[]`

Comment: Thanks Maciej! Corrected

Answer (score 1):

My answer follows what you have written:

> All classes inherit from one Component class. This function in a certain way searches for objects that are instances of these classes.

So in the solution I am using some base class `Component` and to search for some subclass members `SubComponent`.

```
// some empty classes
class Component {}
class SubComponent extends Component {}

function findObjects(...args: Component[]): SubComponent[] { 
  return args.filter(el => el instanceof SubComponent); // do some by instanceof for example
}
// using
const results = findObjects(new Component(), new Component(), new SubComponent());
// results is an array only with SubComponent element
```

The definition of the function is following - `findObjects(...args: Component[]): SubComponent[]`.

- `...args: Component[]` - we take as arguments unknown number of Component instances
- `: SubComponent[]` - we return array of `SubComponents`

I would propose to change little bit definition of this, as we return array, then better would be to take also array:

```
function findObjects(arr: Component[]): SubComponent[] { 
  return arr.filter(el => el instanceof SubComponent); // do some instanceof for example
}
// using
const results = findObjects([new Component(), new Component(), new SubComponent()]);
// results is an array only with SubComponent element
```

Pay attention that now the argument is one - `arr` but it is consistent with the output, we put array in, and take array out. Just a suggestion though.